# custom display scaling in ubuntu 18.04lts not working

Tags: display, scaling

```
 ozzy@ozzy-HP-Laptop-15q-bu0xx:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface       text-scaling-factor 1.2
 GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

is there any other way to use display scaling

Comment: try using `dconf-editor` GUI. i don't know why Your settings will not be saved?

Comment: ive installed dconf editor now how do i change the settings

Comment: just type `dconf-editor`find and select `org.gnome.desktop.interface` and choose `text-scaling-factor` and edit from `1` to `1.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using Gsettings GUI, open it with

```
dconf-editor
```

find your SCHEMADIR,

```
org.gnome.desktop.interface
```

and choose `text-scaling-factor`
finally change a value from `1` to `1.2`

Hope this helps.